# PDFLib.js field.constructor.name return "t" after build

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to fill pdf form usinf PDFLib js.
In my localhost it works fine but after deployment "field.constructor.name" return "t" type. and the data is no filled.
there is no error, but nothing happened.

```
    const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes);

        // Register the `fontkit` instance
        pdfDoc.registerFontkit(fontkit);

        // Embed our custom font in the document
        const customFont = await pdfDoc.embedFont(fontBytes, { subset: true });

        // Get the form containing all the fields
        const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
        const fields = form.getFields()
        fields.forEach(field => {
        //HERE THE PROBLEM!!

        const type = field.constructor.name // GOT "t"
        const name = field.getName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The font file was problematic.

Comment: Hey what changes do I need to make for this. Can you please help me?